# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hdfs': 'hdfs' using subprocess popen in crontab

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, hadoop, hdfs

I use subprocess.popen in python3 to put files or make directories in hdfs. it runs accurately using python3 on the Linux shell. but as I use crontab to run the code, I get "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hdfs': 'hdfs'" Error on my log file.

```
 make_dir = subprocess.Popen(['hdfs','dfs','-mkdir' , '-p' , hdfs_path])
```

Comment: It could be a couple of things, but my feeling is that it is the crontab user that does not have access to `hdfs` you can setup crontab for a specific user by running `crontab -u <some specific user>`

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem when my script executed by **Airflow** in the same machine, Airflow did not load my environment variables. I had to manually set the environment variables in code. you can find how to do that in code [here](https://able.bio/rhett/how-to-set-and-get-environment-variables-in-python--274rgt5#:%7E:text=To%20set%20and%20get%20environment%20variables%20in%20Python%20you%20can,Get%20environment%20variables%20USER%20%3D%20os.). just update `PATH` to include Hadoop binaries path. also it is suggested that you can load environment variables in cron job script. like:

```
#!/bin/bash
source $HOME/.bash_profile
some_other_cmd
```

[more details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables)